# Data From While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

If I submit the form, how can I pass the value to process.php page if select box are inside the while-loop. Is there any solution or option?

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="process.php" >
<?php 
    $endDate = '2014-01-28';
    $startDate = '2014-01-27';

    $daydiff = floor( ( strtotime( $endDate ) - strtotime( $startDate ) ) / 86400 );

    $x=0; 
    while($x<=$daydiff)
    {
        ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="day_name">Day Name</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="day_name">
                    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
                    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                    <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="time">time</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="time">
                    <option value="10am">10am</option>
                    <option value="11am">11am</option>
                    <option value="12pm">12pm</option>
                    <option value="1pm">1pm</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        <?php
        $x++;
    } 
?>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: $_POST['day_name'], $_POST['time']

Comment: your question is not clear.first of all i cant see  $_POST['day_name'] and $_POST['time']  anywhere in your code.present the required code.

Comment: your question is not clear ??? what do you want...if you submit the form then only you can get $_POST and you need to have form tag

Comment: you want the selected box or all options?

Comment: How can I retrieve the value from combo box if my combo box are inside while looping?

Answer (score 0):

First change the HTML code by adding number to end of the select box names.
Then add new hidden variable to keep the select box count.

```
$endDate = $_POST['enddate'];
$startDate = $_POST['startdate'];

$daydiff = floor(( strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate) ) / 86400);

$x = 0;
while ($x <= $daydiff) {
    ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="day_<?php echo $x; ?>">
        <option value="monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" name="time_<?php echo $x; ?>">
        <option value="10am">10am</option>
        <option value="11am">11am</option>
        <option value="12pm">12pm</option>
        <option value="1pm">1pm</option>
    </select>
    <?php
    $x++;
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $x ?>"/>
```

Use this code in your form submit to take the requited data.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['count']; $i++) {
    $day_var = 'day_' . $i;
    $days_list[] = $_POST[$day_var];

    $time_var = 'time_' . $i;
    $time_list[] = $_POST[$time_var];
}

print_r($days_list);
print_r($time_list);
```

Comment: I try your code and its work but. It just store 1 value for each array.

Comment: @canyon Please can you check this again. I have changed the from submit data collection code. it works for me. This is the sample data array, that I have used to test the code. $_POST= array(
    'day_0' => 0,
    'day_1' => 1,
    'day_2' => 2,
    'time_0' => 0,
    'time_1' => 1,
    'time_2' => 2,
    'count' => 3
);

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the value because all the `<select>` box created in the While loop have the same name. Please change the name of these select box. Try below code to render the `<select>`box:

```
<?php 
   $endDate = $_POST['enddate'];
   $startDate = $_POST['startdate'];

   $daydiff = floor( ( strtotime( $endDate ) - strtotime( $startDate ) ) / 86400 );

   $x=0; 
   while($x<=$daydiff)
   {?>
      <select class="form-control" name="day_name_<?php echo $x;?>">
        <option value="monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
      </select>
      <select class="form-control" name="time_<?php echo $x;?>">
        <option value="10am">10am</option>
        <option value="11am">11am</option>
        <option value="12pm">12pm</option>
        <option value="1pm">1pm</option>
      </select>
      <?php                             
      $x++;
   }?>
```

Now, retrieve these values in while loop also by preserving `$daydiff` variable value;

Answer (score 0):

```
$selectOption = $_POST['day_name'];

<select class="form-control" name="day_name">
        <option value="monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
</select>
```